# Problem after Create Setup file Python Project (PyQt5) with cx Freez in user

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, cx-freeze, pyrcc

Several of my own projects, which are separate independent programs, were created by myself after converting the Python file to an `exe` file in my own system and virtual machines. I encounter an unknown error that I have not encountered before. The program specifications were created in Python with `PyQt5` and converted to an executable `.exe` file by `cxFreez`. The content of the file is like the example below:

```
- /Application_Folder
---- /assestFolder
---- /libFolder 
---- mainFile.exe
---- file01.exe [or file01.py]
---- file02.exe [or file02.py]
---- file03.exe [or file03.py]
---- media_rc.py # convert and generated from pyrcc5 in pyqt5 tools
---- media.qrc
```

I also output by default in my system that this problem persisted and I created a `new virtual machine (env)` and installed all the required packages in it first and then output by a `setup.py` file whose contents are as follows :

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os", "PyQt5", "Blockthon", "requests", "random"],
    "excludes": ["tkinter"],
    "bin_includes": ["sip"],
    "bin_path_includes": ["./env/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/bin/"],
    "bin_path_excludes": ["./env/"],
    "include_files": ['assestFolder/', 'libFolder/']
}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(
    script="mainFile.py",
    base=base,
    target_name = "mainFile.exe",
    target_dir = "output"
)

setup(
    name="name_of_your_application",
    version="0.1",
    description="Your application description",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[exe]
)
```

[The image is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwDXz.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.